# Am I able to use Office UI Fabric in a React-Native application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, office-fabric

I've tried adding Microsoft's Office UI Fabric framework to my React-Native project. However, whenever I do this, I am no longer able to run my emulator through Android Studio. Is Fabric not supported in React-Native?

Installed Fabric through Powershell:
    `npm install office-ui-fabric-react --save`

Started Android Emulator through Powershell:
    `react-native run-android`

Received Error Message: `Command 'run-android' unrecognized. Make sure that you have run 'npm install' and that you are inside a react-native project.`

If I uninstall Fabric, `run-android` works as expected. I've had no problems using Fabric in a web app project.

Comment: After installiing fabric, try npm install and then react-native run-android